# How to handle 'Clicked' event in Flex Button control template in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I'm trying to create a custom control template for a Flex Button [-NuGet Available here-](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Forms.Controls.FlexButton/) to have a specific format for the button. The problem is that when I create any template for the button, all the events does not respond to handlers, for example, click event never fires, unless I use contentpresenter which messes with the whole template design.

So is there any way that I can reattach the click -And preferably all the other- click event without using content presenter ?

Here is my template code so far:

```xml
<Style TargetType="flex:FlexButton" x:Key="IconTextButton">
        <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding Path=BackgroundColor}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="{TemplateBinding Path=ForegroundColor}" Text="{TemplateBinding Path=Icon}">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <On Platform="Android">FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awsome 5 Free Solid</On>
                                    <On Platform="iOS">Font Awsome 5 Free</On>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>

                        <Label Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Subtitle" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{TemplateBinding Path=ForegroundColor}" Text="│"/>

                        <Label Grid.Column="3" FontSize="Subtitle" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{TemplateBinding Path=ForegroundColor}" Text="{TemplateBinding Path=Text}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And this is an implementation sample:

```xml
<flex:FlexButton Icon="&#xf002;" Text="Explore" Style="{StaticResource IconTextButton}" Clicked="SampleButton_Clicked"/>
```

And even though everything looks fine, but the `SampleButton_Clicked` is never executed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your style completely, Can you see  Explore text when you display the `flex:FlexButton`?

I made a test, when I remove your `style`, `Clicked` or `TouchedUp` event could be executed normally on the Explore text.

Basded on my research, Your style like a image to cover the `flex:FlexButton`, I cannot see the `Explore text`, so I cannot to click it.

But when I add `TapGestureRecognizer` for the `flex:FlexButton`, it worked as normal. Here is my background code.

```
  var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("user", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(),"Ok");
            };

  flexbtn.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

Here is layout code.

```
<flex:FlexButton Icon="&#xf002;" x:Name="flexbtn" Text="Explore" Style="{StaticResource IconTextButton}"  TouchedUp="FlexButton_Clicked" Clicked="FlexButton_Clicked"  />
```

Here is my running GIF(I cannot reproduce your style completely, I try my best to reproduce it, but it seems still not good looking).

[image]

Comment: You are probably not able to rebuild everything because I'm using `fontawsome` as well as the Flex Button addon, however, I could manage to tweak your solution code to work with my original project on a larger scale. Thanks a lot for your help, wouldn't have done it without you <3. But still, if you found any better way in making all the events handlers work with the normal way, please let me know ^-^.

Comment: One more thing, I added `Margin="{TemplateBinding Path=Padding}"` inside my style, and then when I set the `Padding` inline in the button design it works, but if I added multiple buttons and added the `Padding` in the container resources, it doesn't work, even though all other setters in the same container resources style works...